# Visual Studio - Resx File default 'internal' to 'public'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Every time I edit a resource file in VS, it regenerates the corresponding code and sets the class access modifier to internal.
It's a pain to Ctrl-F -> ReplaceAll every time I edit the resx. Is there a property/setting so that I can default this to public?

```
internal class MyResource {

     internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {...}

}
```

I need all those `internal` to be `public` all the time.

Comment: @jvanrhyn: Because I need to access its resource manager from another project in the solution.

Answer (score 449, accepted):

Instead of the `ResXFileCodeGenerator`, use the `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

You can do this by setting this as the **Custom Tool** property in the **Property** Window for the Resx file you want public access to.

*Edit*: Alternatetively you can set the Access Modifier to public when you open the resx file in Visual Studio. The Access Modifier dropdown box can be found at the top of the form.

Comment: (Good answer; but just some notes; it could also be `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator`, not just `ResXFileCodeGenerator`; and note also that the "Access Modofier" dropdown is often disabled)

Comment: @Anton: Thanks, works in my case. Also, I noticed that changing access modifier from the drop down changes the corresponding tool.

Comment: @conqenator: that's why I proposed using the Access Modifier dropdown as an alternative way of reaching the same outcome :)

Comment: @Anton: Thanks. Most people new to resource files miss the modifier drop down. In a rush project, I went so far as to manually strong type each resource name.

Comment: Jup, I'm another one who missed the modifier dropdown until I found this answer! Thanks @Anton!

Comment: BTW if the Access Modifier dropdown is disabled, you can try changing the Custom Tool property to ResXFileCodeGenerator, if that's not the value alredy. At least that work for me in an MVC project on VS 2010.

Comment: So that's still a click for each resx. Any way to make VS create them public by default?

Comment: For me with Visual Studio 2017 choosing the `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` only makes the Resources class public, not its constructor.

Comment: It works fine for Visual Studio for Mac 2019 as well.

Answer (score 28):

1. Right click on **Resource file** ( `resource.resx` ) => **Properties**.
2. **Custom Tool** => Change to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`

Answer (score 7):

In your .csproj change for each .Designer.cs

```
<Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
```

To

```
<Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
```

Or from the interface

[image]

Hope it's help

Answer (score -11):

Perhaps the easiest way is to create a derived class with a Public ctor?

The generated class:

```
 [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal Strings() {
    }
```

The derived class:

```
public class PublicStrings : Strings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Public localization Strings.
    /// </summary>
    public PublicStrings()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. You will get an error CS0060 Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Strings' is less accessible than class 'PublicStrings'

Comment: This answer can be simply removed.