# How to read global resource file

Tags: c#

I have a window based application in c#. Where i am displaying some message box based on language selected.Its working fine with Form level resources but what if i want to access global resource file(project level).

```
ResourceManager res_man = new ResourceManager("Resources",typeof(Form2).Assembly); 
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        string s = res_man.GetString("String1");
        MessageBox.Show("Arabic-" + s);
```

I tried this but any how not working

For updated ans
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change Current Culture in place of UI culture -

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
```

I am using following code for fetching specific value from Global Resource for specific culture -

```
ResourceManager myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.Strings));
String currencySymbol = myManager.GetString("Currency", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: "Resources.Strings" not accessible to me and please describe what CurrencySymbol  is ?

Comment: "CurrencySymbol" is just a variable in which you hold the value. I am updating answer.

Comment: but still Resources.Strings not accessible to me. I am adding a screen shot. Please see in question panel

Comment: "Resources.Strings" is the name of Resource file from where you want to fetch data. It will be like **Strings.en-GB.resx** in **App_GlobalResources** folder

Comment: Can you please clear one thing, if i am having two global resources files one for English and one for Arabic than ?

Comment: make a default file with **Strings.resx** name and for specific language create file with corresponding language code. e.g. for Great Britain it will be **Strings.en-GB.resx**. Check Language code from this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Follow this link for details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247246(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You know one thing, if i add resource file Strings.resx . this is shown for "Resources.Strings" but if i rename this with "Strings.en-GB.resx" than its not accessible for "Resources.Strings"

Comment: Having one file without any language code is mandatory. **Strings.resx** will be default for all languages. then add new resource file for each language with its corresponding language code. e.g. "Strings.en-GB.resx"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62575/discussion-between-user1280492-and-vikash-singh).

Answer (score 2):

Access Modifier is by default internal. Did you use the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator ?

You can set the Access Modifier to public when you open the RESX file in Visual Studio. There is a  dropdown box that can be found at the top of the form which changes the Access Modifier.

And after that you will be able to access :

```
var resxManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resource));
var currentString = resxManager.GetString("Practitioner", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Here can be a related issue : [Visual Studio - Resx File default 'internal' to 'public'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274311/visual-studio-resx-file-default-internal-to-public)