# Resource file can't be access in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, c1-cms

In my composite c1 razor template I try to get the value from Resource.resx file.But I can't access the resource file it showing 'The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current content.I already added the resource file inside the App_GlobalResources folder.

Can any one help how to access the resource file inside my razor code.
here is my code

```
@inherits RazorPageTemplate
@using System.Resources;
@functions {
    public override void Configure()
    {
        TemplateId = new Guid("2c6536fd-af20-4d41-ae40-f6a09eb6fc74");
        TemplateTitle = "InnerPage_En";
        Layout = "InnerPageMasterLayOut.cshtml";
    }

Thanks in advance for help
    [Placeholder(Id = "content", Title = "Content", IsDefault = true)]
    public XhtmlDocument Content { get; set; }

    [Placeholder(Id = "bottom", Title = "Bottom")]
    public XhtmlDocument Bottom { get; set; }

}
@{

    var tes = Resources.Resource.Test;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set Access Modifier Drop Down to public in resource file and check

[image]

Comment: I can't change the Access Modifier ,in my file it is disabled.

Comment: go through this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274311/visual-studio-resx-file-default-internal-to-public