# "The member "X" is not recognized or is not accessible." error in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make an interface with multiple language options on a WPF screen. I'm writing the name of the text block I want to add to my Resources file and my code, but on the xaml screen "The member "Manuals" is not recognized or is not accessible." I get an error. I am getting this error in all the buttons and texts I try to add. Can you help me understand why? There is my xaml code line and resources designer cs project code line.  Thanks in advance.

```
public static string _Manual
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Manuals", resourceCulture);
        }
    } 

<TextBlock  Name="ttbManuals" Grid.Row="8" Text="{x:Static resx:Resources._Manual}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-20"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="580" Style="{DynamicResource CncTextBlock}" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush1}" Padding="10,5,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially the section *DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.*

Comment: ResourceManager has access to the content of a *.resx file.
If you want the string value of a resource named "Manuals" "Manuals" needs to have been added to the resx file the manager wraps around.
If your "Manuals" is the name of a WPF textbox, it won't work.
The content of a WPF Textbox is accessed very straight forwardly through `myTextBox.Text`.
In your case `Manuals.Text`.

Comment: @Clemens sorry i am not very familiar with asking questions on stacoverflow i will be careful.

Comment: Then edit your question please.

Comment: resx file with the same name, but the textbox name is different. I checked many times to see if there is something I wrote differently, but I couldn't find it. @lidqy

Comment: I hope it's better this way. @Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Resources` class is by default created as `internal`. For use in XAML it needs however to be `public`.

To fix it, select the resx file in solution explorer and in the properties, change `ResXFileCodeGenerator` to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

[image]

See also here: [Visual Studio - Resx File default 'internal' to 'public'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274311/visual-studio-resx-file-default-internal-to-public)

Comment: i try this. My resx file is public now. But i still got the same error :(

Comment: The Resources (cs) class must be public. This is (at least normally) created by VisualStudio from the resx file.